# alt-shift toggles keymap when part of a shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have two xkb layouts, and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to toggle between them:

```
setxkbmap "fr,us" -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

However, when I press a shorcut which contains <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the shortcut isn't taken into account, and instead the layout switches. For example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (which selects code to the matching closing paren in some editors), or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> (which is search and replace in emacs, the <kbd>%</kbd> needing <kbd>Shift</kbd> on French keyboards).

This was not the case with XUbuntu 14.04 I think, but I switched to NixOs, and I now have this issue.

How can I configure `setxkbmap` so that it switches layouts only when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is not part of a shortcut, i.e. upon releasing the keys and only if there wasn't another key pressed at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/setxkbmap/-/issues/10#note_1619232) in xkb. sxhkd would be a better solution and gives you better control.

Add this to sxhkdrc:

```
Shift_L + Alt_L
    setxkbmap -query | grep -q 'fr' && setxkbmap us || setxkbmap fr,us
Shift_R + Alt_R
    setxkbmap -query | grep -q 'fr' && setxkbmap us || setxkbmap fr,us
```

Note that for some reason, `alt` must be pressed before `shift` to be detected by sxhkd.